# which version of Jprofiler to use?

Tags: jboss, jprofiler, java1.4

I am working on app that is built on Java 1.4 and is hosted on Jboss 2.4.

I want to install jprofiler and connect to JVM to profile my app.

I wanted to know which version is compatible with my app before i go ahead purchase the license?

Answer (score 1):

I am using version 7 for java 1.4